# triggerring same bokeh callback from multiple widgets

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have been building a bokeh plot that includes two different widgets, aside from the plot itself. One is a drop-down menu and the other is a "clear plot" button.

As things are now, the "clear plot" button makes a callback to a function that clears all points from the plot. The drop down menu is for selecting values that will change plotting limits. This latter widget I would like also to reset the plot, just like the button click

Since the Button widget has `on_event` style events, and the Select widget has `on_change` style events, I have a hard time figuring out how I can make a callback to the same function (the one that clears the plot), as the two event types require different arguments in the callback.

```
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick 
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select

plot_data = ColumnDataSource(dict(id=[],step=[],ratio=[]))

***some code that populates the ColumnDataSoure***

#Defining button function for resetting alarms
button = Button(label="RESET ALARMS", button_type="danger")

def reset_plot(event):
    #Resetting plot
    plot_data.data = {k: [] for k in plot_data.data}

button.on_event(ButtonClick,reset_plot)
```

My `Select` widget is currently looking like this:

```
menu = [(str(item),str(item)) for item in list_of_items]
dropdown = Select(title='Item', value="Item 1",options=menu)

def change_limits(attr,old,new):
   *some code that changes the plotting limits*

dropdown.on_change('value',change_limits)
```

What I would like is basically something like a `dropdown.on_change("select new item",reset_plot)` callback.

Is it possible to somehow make a callback to my `reset_plot` function from the `Select`widget, or do I simply have to write up the same functionality inside my `change_limits` function?

The latter would probably work, but it seems clumsy to have identical pieces of code buried in two different functions, and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow make a callback to my reset_plot function from the Selectwidget, or do I simply have to write up the same functionality inside my change_limits function?

Bokeh server callbacks are not different from any other python functions, and they themselves can be called, or call other functions, in the exact same way as any other contexts. In this situation, it sounds like you should factor out the common code to your own "clear" function an then both callbacks can call that.